# Unsetting multiple php pages

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-cookies, unset

I have multiple pages in php. What i want is when you click the back button and you're logged out, that certain page will not display. Say, i clicked home, then logged out, display log in form and when back button on the browser is pressed, it will say you're logged out. I tried session destroy, clear cookies but it doesn't seem to work(or I'm doing it wrong). I am new to php and I am still in the process of learning it. Do you have any suggestions? O.O I have my code here:

here is my index.php

```
 <?php

     require 'core.inc.php';

     if(isset($_SESSION['user'])&&!empty($_SESSION['user'])){
      include 'home.php';
      $html_block1 = "<script language='javascript'>
                                    alert('Welcome');
                                    </script> ";
      echo $html_block1;
     }else{

       include 'loginform.inc.php';

     }


?>
```

then my loginform

```
    <?php


    if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['user'])&& !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
       $_username = $_POST['user'];
       $_password = $_POST['pass'];

       $_passwordhash = md5($_password);

       $_file = 'password.txt';
       $handle = fopen($_file,'r');
       $_pass_from_file =fread($handle,1024);
       trim($_pass_from_file);

                  if($_username == 'il' && ($_passwordhash == $_pass_from_file)){
                      $_SESSION ['user'] = $_username;
                      header('Location: index.php');
                  } else {
                      $html_block1 = "<script language='javascript'>
                                     alert('Incorrect password');
                                     </script> ";
                   echo $html_block1;
                  }
       fclose($handle);
    } else {
          unset($_username);
    }


?>
        <form class="form" method ="POST" type="loginform.inc.php" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name ="user" >
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name = "pass" >
              <input type  = "submit"   value = "Login">
               <input type  = "submit"   value = "Change password" name = "change">
        </form>
```

my core

```
 <?php

     ob_start();
     session_start();
     clearstatcache();

?>
```

home

```
    <?php
    echo 'Hi! you\'re home<br>';
    echo '<a href = "other.php">please click link to next page</a><br>';
    echo '<a href = "logout.php">logout???</a>';
 ?>
```

other page

```
 <?php
    echo "Hi<br>";
    echo '<a href = logout.php>logout?</a>'
?>
```

and my log out

```
<?php
session_destroy();
header('Location: loginform.inc.php');
ob_flush();
?>
```

Suggestions or edits are welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: add `session_start()` at top on loginform file

Comment: @saty it still doing the same thing :(

Comment: write `session_start()` in every page  on top where you use session on your page!!

Comment: alright O_o . im sorry

Comment: It's fine @ClaireFatimaInodeo, PHP `sessions` require you to have `session` start at the top of every page before any content has been echo'd by PHP. Furthermore you don't need `ob_flush` In your script. You can just remove it to make things simpler @ the start ;)